# How to get max interval value?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In the BQ Docs on [Interval](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#interval_type), it says the max value is:

[image]

Is there a single way to input that value, or is it only possible by adding the three parts together, such as:

```
SELECT INTERVAL '10000-0' year to month + INTERVAL 3660000 day + INTERVAL 87840000 hour
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can enter it in in the canonical format using the date unit range `YEAR TO SECOND`. For example:

```
SELECT INTERVAL '10000-0 3660000 87840000:0:0' YEAR TO SECOND
```

[image]

And you can easily see that is the max value then:

[image]